# LWC when lightning data table save multiple rows get error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, updaterecord

I have a lightning data table, I am able to edit 1 row and save it, but if I edit 2 rows and save, I get the error. Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

```
     HTML:
        <template>
 <lightning-button class="slds-m-bottom_medium slds-align_absolute-center" variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSave4}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-card title = "Accordion and Lightning datatable" icon-name="standard:opportunity">
                <template if:true={tableData}>
                    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class="wrapper">
                        <div for:each={tableData} for:item="item" key={item.Id} >
                            <div class="slds-p-top_small"></div>
                            <lightning-accordion-section label={item.Name} class="slds-p-left_small container">
    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
                                 <lightning-datatable
                                key-field="Id"                
                                data={item.header}               
                                columns={opptyColumns}
                                onsave={handleSaveOppty}
                                oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                                draft-values={draftValues} 
                                                              
                                >
                                </lightning-datatable>   
                            </div>               
                                <div class="slds-p-around_small slds-m-left_large">
                                    <div class="text-section slds-p-around_small">
                                        <div class="slds-text-heading-medium">Technology</div>
                                    </div>                          
                                     <lightning-datatable                                         
                                                    key-field="Id"
                                                    data={item.lines}
                                                    columns={techLineColumns}
                                                    onsave={handleSaveOpptyLine}
                                                    draft-values={techDraftValues}>
                                            </lightning-datatable>
                                </div>
                            </lightning-accordion-section>                
                        </div>
                    </lightning-accordion>
                </template>
                <template if:true={error}>{error}</template>
            </lightning-card>
            <div class="slds-p-bottom_medium"></div>
        </template>
        
        JS:
        import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
        import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
        import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
        
        import getOpportunitiesWithLines from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getOpportunitiesWithLines'
        
        export default class SaveDatatable extends LightningElement {
           
            techDraftValues = [];
            @track refreshTable = [];
            tableData =[]
            error
        
        
            @wire(getOpportunitiesWithLines)
            opportunitiesWithLines({data, error}){
                if(data){
                    console.log(data)   
                   this.formatTableData(data)
               
                }
                if(error){
                    console.error(error)
                    this.error = error
                }
            }
          opptyColumns =[     
            {
              
                label: 'Name',
                fieldName: 'Name',
                type: 'text',
                editable: true
            },
            {
              
                label: 'Stage',
                fieldName: 'StageName',
                type: 'text',
                editable: true
            }
        ]
    
        
             techLineColumns =[            
                {
                    label: 'Product value($000s)',
                    fieldName: 'Product_Value__c',
                    type: 'currency',
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Expected Term',
                    fieldName: 'Term_in_Months__c',
                    type: 'text',
                    editable: true
                }
            ]
           
            formatTableData(result){
                this.tableData = result.map(item => {
                    const {OpportunityLineItems, Id, DealID__c, Name, StageName, CloseDate, Renewal_Notes__c, Primary_Partner__c} = item
                    const headerArray =[
                        {Id, 
                        Name, 
                        StageName, 
                        CloseDate,                    
        
                        }
                    ];
                    
                    return {"Id": Id, "Name": Name,"header": [...headerArray], "lines": OpportunityLineItems}
                })
              
            }
        
          
            handleSaveOpptyLine(event) {
                let techDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
                const recordInputs =  event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
                    const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
                    return { fields };
                });
            
                console.log('RECORDINPUTS', JSON.stringify(recordInputs));
            
                const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
                Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            
                     this.techDraftValues = [];
            
                     return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error updating the record", error)
                })
            }
        }
async handleSaveAll() {
       
        // Prepare the record IDs for getRecordNotifyChange()
        const notifyChangeOpptyIds = this.opptyDraftValuesArray.map(row => { return { "recordId": row.Id } });
        const notifyChangeOpptyLineIds = this.opptyLineDraftValuesArray.map(row => { return { "recordId": row.Id } });
    
        try {
            // Pass edited fields to the updateContacts Apex controller
            const result = await updateOpportunitiesAndLines({opptyData: this.opptyDraftValuesArray, opptyLinesData: this.opptyLineDraftValuesArray});
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Apex update result: "+ result));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Opportunity/Lines updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
    
            // Refresh LDS cache and wires
            getRecordNotifyChange(notifyChangeOpptyIds);
            getRecordNotifyChange(notifyChangeOpptyLineIds);
    
        //call refresh to do refreshapex        
        this.refresh();  
       }
       catch(error) {
            console.error('error ', error)
               this.dispatchEvent(
                   new ShowToastEvent({
                       title: 'Error updating or refreshing records',
                     
                       message: error,
                       variant: 'error'
                   })
             );
        };
    }
  
    refresh() {         
        refreshApex(this.wiredResults)
            .then(() => {
                this.opptyDraftValues = [];    
                this.techDraftValues = [];          
                this.servDraftValues = [];               
                this.opptyDraftValuesArray = [];  
                this.opptyLineDraftValuesArray = [];  
               
            }).catch();
        }
Apex:
 @AuraEnabled
        public static string updateOpportunitiesAndLines(Object opptyData, Object opptyLinesData) {
            List<Opportunity> opportunitiesForUpdate;
            List<OpportunityLineItem> opptyLinesForUpdate;
            
            if(opptyData != null && opptyData.size != 0){
                    opportunitiesForUpdate = (List<Opportunity>) JSON.deserialize(
                        JSON.serialize(opptyData), List<Opportunity>.class);
            }
            if(opptyLinesData != null && opptyLinesData.size != 0){
                    opptyLinesForUpdate = (List<OpportunityLineItem>) JSON.deserialize(
                        JSON.serialize(opptyLinesData), List<OpportunityLineItem>.class );
            }
           
            if(opportunitiesForUpdate != null || opptyLinesForUpdate != null){
                    try {
                        if(opportunitiesForUpdate != null ){                          
                            update opportunitiesForUpdate;                      
                        }
                         if(opptyLinesForUpdate != null){ 
                            update opptyLinesForUpdate;
                        }
                        
                        return 'Success: Opportunities/Lines updated successfully';
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
                    }
             }
             return 'No records to update';
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Contact uses its parent Account for row locking. Perhaps OpportunityLineItem and Opportunity behave in a similar way. Perhaps changing this record at a time update `recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput))` to a single bulk request/transaction (likely needing a bit of Apex) will avoid the problem.

Comment: @KeithC, thank you! But why editing/saving 1 record does not having 'locking error'? I will try Apex to save.

Comment: Hi Lei, The first `updateRecord` call applies the lock (to the Opportunity) then when the second `updateRecord` tries to obtain it it can't. Note I'm guessing here, but if this was my code I'd try the single bulk call approach to see if that fixed it or not.

Comment: Hi Keith, I wrote an Apex to save opportunity lines, it works fine. But actually, the requirement is show Opportunity and its Opportunity Lines, so I have 2 lightning data table, 1 lighting data table has Opportunity info , 2nd lighting data table has Opportunity  Line info, when Saving, in Apex should I save Opportunity record first, then Opportunity Lines records? What is the best practice? thanks

Comment: Hi Lei, You will need to save the Opportunity first which will automatically set the `Id` value on your Apex variable and then pass that into the lines to hook them up to that as their parent.

Comment: Hi Keith, thank you so much for the reply. I updated the code above: 1) A 'Save' button outside 2 lightning data tables( Opportunity, Opportunities) 2) 1 apex method to updateOppty and updateOpptyLines. My question:  since updateOppty and updateOpptyLines are executed in 1 transaction,  when updateOpptyLines are called, the lines will still be hooked to their parent? thanks again!

Comment: That's great! Keith